# @protocol não está funcionando

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou implementando um protocolo mais o mesmo não está conseguindo efetuar a chamada do `delegate`:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addCard)]) {
    [self.delegate addCard];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)addCard;
@end


@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;


- (IBAction)setCard:(id)sender;

@end




#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PSWallet.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}



- (IBAction)setCard:(id)sender {

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addCard)]) {
        [self.delegate addCard];
    }
}
@end
```

**PSWallet.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface PSWallet : NSObject<ViewControllerDelegate>

@end


#import "PSWallet.h"


@interface PSWallet ()

@end

@implementation PSWallet

-(void)addCard{


    NSLog(@"not work");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu `delegate` é um `id<ViewControllerDelegate>` e na definição do protocolo `ViewControllerDelegate` o método `addCard` não é opcional. Sendo assim a checagem `[self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addCard)]` é teoricamente desnecessária.

Seu código deveria funcionar. Você está setando o `delegate` no seu `ViewController`? Há ao menos uma referência `strong` para ele?

Seu código compila e funciona bem aqui setando o `delegate`.